# Conversion of BitmapImage to Byte array and Store it Into Sql Database

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to store bitmap image to byte, but in run time i'm getting error like

> Conversion From type Image Format to Type Integer is Not Valid

Please Any one Help Me

```
For Each file As UploadedFile In` DOC.UploadedFiles`
                Context.Cache.Remove(Session.SessionID + "UploadedFile")
                Dim stream As Stream = file.InputStream
                GenerateThumbnails(0.5, stream)

                Dim DocumentImgName = file.FileName
                Dim imgData As Byte() = New Byte(ViewState("CompressedImageData")) {}
                Dim DocumentSplit = DocumentImgName.Split(".")

                Dim ImgName = DocumentSplit(0)
                Dim ImgExt = DocumentSplit(1)

                stream.Read(imgData, 0, imgData.Length)

                ViewState("imgData") = imgData
                ViewState("FileName") = ImgName
                ViewState("FileExtension") = ImgExt

                Dim ms As New MemoryStream()

                ms.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length)
   Next

Private Sub GenerateThumbnails(ByVal scaleFactor As Double, ByVal sourcePath As Stream)

   Using image__1 = Image.FromStream(sourcePath)

            ' can given width of image as we want
            Dim newWidth = CInt(image__1.Width * scaleFactor)

            ' can given height of image as we want
            Dim newHeight = CInt(image__1.Height * scaleFactor)

            Dim thumbnailImg = New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
            Dim thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg)

            thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

            Dim imageRectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)

            thumbGraph.DrawImage(image__1, imageRectangle)

            ViewState("CompressedImageData") = image__1.RawFormat

        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Store an Image data after Convert it to Byte datatype as below:

```
Dim ms As New Syste.IO.MemoryStream
Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
Dim byteImage() As Byte = ms.ToArray
```

Then You can Store The byteImage() to a field wich its type is Image Or Varbinary.

Comment: i didn't use any picture box in my application , then what should do? , and thank you so much for this answer